# Editing APK without the source?

Tags: java, android

i had made an android app
i want to share this app with a person
the person must replace 1 line code in the source so it works for him (it is a link in the source)
but the thing is that i don't want to give the source to anyone .

is there is a way to edit and apk file and change the link to his own link 
if there is a way i think i could automate the thing , i could make a .exe file when he press it it will ask him for the link when he press OK it will edit the apk for him then give it to him
is this scenario possible ?

Comment: Is there any chance you could move the portions that need to be mutable to a separate configuration file (particularly if the value you need to change is a string literal)?

Comment: Just store it in Preferences

Comment: Just change the link and rebuild a version for him.  I'm curious though, what is the scenario?  Why do people need different links?  there maybe a better solution to your problem.

Comment: hardcode both links. Then at run time use an if statement that checks something unique about your device vs. his device (i.e. phone # or Gmail address) to determine which to use. That way you don't have to do any build shenanigans. And you are assured that the wrong person will not get the wrong link.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this you can put file containing URL to raw resource folder. Your friend can unarchive apk, change url and compress apk back. No special "hacker" skills required.
But you better add this url to preferences and let your friend type it by himself.

P.S. you can edit source code. But it's quite tricky )

Comment: ok i had un archived my apk throught 7zip i found classes.dex , resources.arsc , AndroidManifest, META-INF, res . files are encrypted i cant read them ... where is the file my friend must modify ?

Comment: first put file in raw resource folder with url. then build apk. unarchive it. find your file. change it. compress apk. profit )